# Problems with calculating Law of Sines

Tags: python, python-3.8

In my math class we are currently in a basic trigonometry unit, with Law of Sines/Law of Cosines. I occasionally write programs that let me input known values and get answers from that input when I am bored.

I am struggling with the Law of Sines Side/Side/Angle rules, however. I am using this problem as a test (apologies for the quality):
[image: The problem worked out on paper:]

When worked out on paper, it equals roughly 15 degrees.

This is the code I have in place:

```
# SSA
x = float(input("Known Angle Degrees: "))
y = float(input("Length of Side Opposite Known: "))
z = float(input("Length of Side Opposite Unknown: "))

a = (math.sin(math.radians(x))/y)*z
b = math.asin(a)

print(str(a))
print(str(b))
```

And this is the result I get:

```
Known Angle Degrees: 48
Length of Side Opposite Known: 63
Length of Side Opposite Unknown: 22
0.2595108914365504
0.26251570863497786
```

It clearly gets everything right until getting the reverse/arc sine of a. I'm just not sure what is wrong here. When getting the value of b, I've tried converting A to radians, and to decimals, and instead of using asin(), using sin() raised to -1. Nothing's worked.

Any ideas?

Edit: Apologies, I did not include that I had imported the `math` module. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing a conversion back from radians to degrees:

```
>>> math.degrees(math.asin(0.2595108914365504))
15.041042160670253
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the radians to degrees conversion as well, so like this:

```
 import math
 angleB = math.degrees(math.asin(0.259))
 print(angleB)
 ### Output is 15 degrees (truncated)
```